# Adding :hover effect to an image

Tags: html, css

Original question: "@Temani Afif help me to put a hover effect on my code ,I am trying to make a hover effect so when any of the images have the mouse hovering over, the shirt scales down and the art scales up.
now I am trying to use his code on my actual site which will have several pages, but for some reason it does not work or it is better to say I don't know how can I make it to work."

Thanks to @Temani Afif again, with his guidance I was able to find the answer , Now I have two problems and one request:
1- I can not center the logo on the shirt.
2-Also when the browser window is fully enlarged the shirt enlarges to its original size and does not go over 100%.
3-How can I simplify the code?

I would appreciate any help.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.anim ');



        observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                    entry.target.style.animation = `square-animation .5s ${entry.target.dataset.delay} forwards ease-out`;
                    
                }
                else {
                    entry.target.style.animation = 'none';
                }
            })

        })

        images.forEach(entry => {
            observer.observe(entry)

                  }) 

const slideup = document.querySelectorAll('.slideup ');

        observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                    entry.target.style.animation = `slideup 1s ${entry.target.dataset.delay} forwards ease-out`;
                    
                }
                else {
                    entry.target.style.animation = 'none';
                }
            })

        })

         
        slideup.forEach(entry => {
            observer.observe(entry)
        
         })



 const scale = document.querySelectorAll('.scale ');

        observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                    entry.target.style.animation = `scale 1s ${entry.target.dataset.delay} forwards ease-out`;
                    
                }
                else {
                    entry.target.style.animation = 'none';
                }
            })

        })

         
        scale.forEach(entry => {
            observer.observe(entry)
        
         })


         const sliding = document.querySelectorAll('.sliding ');

        observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                    entry.target.style.animation = `sliding .5s ${entry.target.dataset.delay} forwards ease-out`;
                    
                }
                else {
                    entry.target.style.animation = 'none';
                }
            })

        })
         
        sliding.forEach(entry => {
            observer.observe(entry)
        
         })
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  }
  .section.one{
    background-color: rgb(6, 65, 65);
  }
  
 

.title-bar {
  
  display: flex;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 8vh;
  max-width: 70vw;
  min-height: 1vh;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1vh;
  border-top-color: #28f7e6;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1vh;
  border-bottom-color: #28f7e6;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }

.title-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 6vh;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    font-family: PT Serif;
    color: #28f7e6;
   }



.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1%;
  max-width:70%;
  margin:auto;
}
.grid-container > div  {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
 
.grid-container > div > .shirt {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  transition: .5s;
}


.grid-container > div > .art {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  
  
}
  
.grid-container > div > .shirt > .slideup {
  max-width: 100%;
  
  /* controls the width of the shirt images */
}

.grid-container > div > .art > .scale {
  max-width: 50%;
  
  
  
  /* controls the width of the art images  */
}
  

.grid-container  div:hover  .shirt {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.grid-container  div:hover .art {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: bottom;
 
}

.anim {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slideup {
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.scale {
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.sliding {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes square-animation {
  0%{
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100%{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideup {
  0%{
    transform: translate(0px,50%);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  
  100%{
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }

}


@keyframes scale {
  0%{
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(0,0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  
  100%{
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  
  100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes sliding {

0%{
  transform: translate(50px,10px);
  opacity: 0;
}


100%{
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HOME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/4.0.11/fullpage.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-NGRhMiWY9pf5z8PLens7/u+LLwIPAu1dhJ7u9sHRWIo8TKrVbKiWlRdYRH3pVDCZA10zmobo+PBLGeLOREklBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section one">
            
            <div class="grid-title-container">

                <div class="title-bar anim" data-delay=".1s">
                    <p class="title-text"> First Banner </p>
                </div>

                <div class="grid-container ">                        
                    <div>
                        <div class="shirt">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oS8QWPI.png" class="slideup" data-delay=".4s">
                        </div>

                        <div class="art">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jeNzULX.png"    class="scale" data-delay="1s">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="shirt">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oS8QWPI.png" class="slideup" data-delay=".6s">
                        </div>
                        <div class="art">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jeNzULX.png"    class="scale" data-delay="1.2s">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="shirt">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oS8QWPI.png" class="slideup" data-delay=".8s">
                        </div>
                        <div class="art">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jeNzULX.png"    class="scale" data-delay="1.4s">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                </div>

           </div>
        </div>
 
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/4.0.11/fullpage.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-ojnoeSkK5NDwnuW5S0ZnddobHez8Bx1yVa3RE+Cd0fGEuY/NEd4sgVF/CJ6eDtnOeLZLbTJpNFrCkUYbHS2hRA=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>"
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script>
            new fullpage('#fullpage', {
                //options here
                autoScrolling: true,
                scrollHorizontally: true
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The JS you are using is interfering with the hover effect, I suggest using those effect on the container rather than the images

Comment: I am assuming I have to put every image inside a div with specific class?

Answer (score -2):

Since wordpress is very customizable,you can design a website with a lot of visual appeal.it may take time and planning to create a unique site but it is very possible when you are using the right techniques

Comment: Please see [answer] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum and this shouldn't have been posted as an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).